# setQueryParameters error parameters format

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have this ionic service but when i pass the parameters in set Queryparametrs function it wont work.

```
var sample = function(title,description,adress,country,userid)
    {

        var req = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/eventAdapter/addEvent", WLResourceRequest.POST);


        req.setQueryParameters("params", "['"+title+","+description+","+adress+","+country+","+userid+"']");





        return req.send().then(function(res) {
         ........

        }, function(bad) {
            .......
        });
    }
```

any help ?

Comment: Mention that MobileFirst version you are using.

Comment: And when you say "won't work", can you provide an actual error message?

Comment: in the response message !!  i think the parameters passed in the setQueryParameters are in wrong format .                                                 Object {statusReason: "OK", responseHeaders: Object, isSuccessful: true, responseTime: 175, totalTime: 175…}
errors
:
Object
isSuccessful
:
true
message
:
"Event validation failed"
name
:
"ValidationError"
responseHeaders
:
Object
responseTime
:
175
statusCode
:
200
statusReason
:
"OK"
totalTime
:
175

Comment: i found this solution and it works but i'm looking for other solutions thanks-------------   var params=[
                  title,
                  description,
                  adress,
                  country,
                  state,
                  userid,
                  
          ];
          var newParams = {'params' : JSON.stringify(params)};
    
      
             
            return req.sendFormParameters(newParams).then(function(res) {

Comment: you didn't get the error or what ?

Answer (score 1):

If your content (`title`, `description`, etc) contains any invalid json characters, it could be that the string you generated is invalid.

As you guessed correctly, using `JSON.stringify` is the safer option.

```
var params = [title, description, adress, country, state, userid];
req.setQueryParameters("params",JSON.stringify(params));
```

Also, your request is using `POST`, and so it is expected to use form parameters instead of query parameters:

```
req.sendFormParameters({"params":JSON.stringify(params)})
```